# Importing text file into excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA code which supposed to delete the data on a selected excel sheet, open a dialog box for text file selection, and then import the data from that text file to the same exact sheet I've deleted the data from. So far I can only open the text file into a new workbook but can't open it to the same sheet I've deleted the data from.

Here's what I came with so far, will appreciate your help:

```
Dim Filt As String
Dim FilterIndex As Integer
Dim Title As String
Dim FileName As Variant

Filt = "Cst Files (*.prn),*.prn"
Title = "Select a cst File to Import"
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=Filt, Title:=Title)

If FileName = False Then
MsgBox "No File Was Selected"
Exit Sub
End If

With Application.ActiveSheet
    Cells.Select
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
End With

Workbooks.Open FileName
```

Answer (score 52):

There are many ways you can import Text file to the current sheet. Here are three (including the method that you are using above)

1. Using a QueryTable
2. Open the text file in memory and then write to the current sheet and finally applying Text To Columns if required.
3. If you want to use the method that you are currently using then after you open the text file in a new workbook, simply copy it over to the current sheet using `Cells.Copy`

**Using a QueryTable**

Here is a simple macro that I recorded. Please amend it to suit your needs.

```
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Sample.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Open the text file in memory**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    Open "C:\Sample.txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Once you have the data in the array you can export it to the current sheet.

**Using the method that you are already using**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Sheet where you want to import

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.txt")

    wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsI.Cells

    wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

You can use the `Application.GetOpenFilename` to choose the relevant file. For example...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Prn Files (*.prn), *.prn")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

            '~~> Rest of the code

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look like the QueryTable method is the most straight forward but is there a way to add a dialog box to it so I'll have an option to choose text files from different sources?

Comment: Yes. One moment... updating the post

Comment: Updated the post :) See `FOLLOWUP`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi, I was wondrin which is the fastest among the above methods presented. I'm just hoping that you already have the answer other than me trying each one of it one by one? Cause the current code I have is long and to adopt to each sample, I need to tweak the entire code to align. I was hoping to skip the determining part and proceed with the fastest way and adjust my code accordingly.

Comment: @SiddharthRout already sorted it out. Fastest would be the 3rd sample. Using the `Workbook.Open` or `Workbook.OpenText` method. If this is somehow not align with your conclusion, please inform me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can write
          .WorkbookConnection.Delete
after 
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
this will delete text file external connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think [my answer to my own question](https://superuser.com/a/731537/45564) here is the simplest solution to what you are trying to do:

1. Select the cell where the first line of text from the file should be.
2. Use the `Data`/`Get External Data`/`From File` dialog to select the text file to import.
3. Format the imported text as required.
4. In the `Import Data` dialog that opens, click on `Properties...`
5. Uncheck the `Prompt for file name on refresh` box.
6. Whenever the external file changes, click the `Data`/`Get External Data`/`Refresh All` button.

Note: in your case, you should probably want to skip step #5.

Comment: But it always asks you to select the file again when you press refresh