# Excel VBA - Import a text file to excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question regarding [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet/11267603#11267603), more specific **Using a query table**

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ "TEXT;***C:\Sample.txt***", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _ )
```

In the example `C:\Sample.txt` is entered statically. How would you make this dynamic and let the user select the file?

Comment: OH!! How could I miss that? It was right there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @t.thielemans post that as the answer to have it upvoted and delete the comment after. Whe he does this Punit will need to accept it

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're looking for this function;

```
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
```

- [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx)
- [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet)

Comment: I was using this function already. But while using the variable name 'filename' I actually missed the '&' to be used before variable name and therefore was getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Public Browse(ByVal i as Integer,ByVal j as Inetger)
   Application.EnableCancelKey=xlDisabled
   Cells(i,j)=Application.GetOpenFileName(,,,,"Select File",,false) 
End Sub

Sub BrowseFile
   Call Browse(8,9) 'Cell no. 
End Sub
```

The BrowseFile can be assigned to the ActiveX Controls Object which can be provided in front end.