# Using Querytable to load Text files

Tags: excel, vba

Currently working on a macro that'll import txt files onto excel spreadsheet...very basic querytable code but I cant seem to integrate the application.getfilename component.

```
Dim DataF
DataF = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
With activesheet.querytables.add(connection:="Text; & DataF", Destination:_
=Range("$A$1"))
End with
```

Code isn't coming up with any errors...but then again the txt data aren't showing up...
I've referred to this previous post [vba: Importing text file into excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet) but still stumped on this basic code.

Anyone here encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything within quotes will be considered as a string whereas `DataF` is a variable.

Try this

```
connection:="Text;" & DataF
```

Also ensure that you check what `DataF` returns as your code can fail if user presses `Cancel`. For example

```
Dim DataF

DataF = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If DataF <> False Then
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End If
```