# import multiple text files to seperate sheets in the existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an excel file (2013) (eg **test.xlsm**). The excel file contains sheets with graphs and pivot tables which are refreshed monthly, based on text files. I need a VBA code which can import multiple text files from my local drive (which I import from a server) and append them at the end (sheets named similar to text file names) in this excel file. Every month, when I import text files, it has to replace this data sheets with new files.

**Problem:**
I have found a VBA code in this [link](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010400_Importing_Multiple_Files_to_a_Single_Workbook.html)! It works perfectly fine. But my problem is it imports the data into a newly opened Workbook instead of existing Workbook.

**Solution**

I modified the lines from

```
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
```

to

```
Set wkbAll = ThisWorkbook
wkbAll.Activate
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(wkbAll.Sheets.Count)
```

but I get **error 1004, no data selected** to format the data with delimiter

```
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
```

**Solution**
I have found the some questions similar to mine (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010080/copying-data-from-a-text-file-to-an-excel-workbook/21010921#21010921)), but none of them worked for me.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code with changes

```
Sub copydata()

    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String


    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
        MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If


    Set wkbAll = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    x = 1

    With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FilesToOpen(x))
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
        .Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
        .Close False
    End With

    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FilesToOpen(x))
            .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
                Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
                Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
            .Sheets(1).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)

        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

    wkbAll.Save
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to format the data with the deliminator in the new sheet?

Comment: @VBA Pete,yes sir, if it can format in the temporary file and copy the data into my excel file, can also be helpful to me

Comment: To better understand you code: Why did you activate the worksheet wkbAll.Activate?

Comment: Because the active workbook was **wkbTemp**, so i activated **wkbAll**.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your full code? It is hard to follow how you changed the code.

Comment: Yes, please share your full code block so we can reproduce. Snippets are not helpful.

Comment: What kind of files are you selecting in the opening window that pops up when you run the code?

Comment: @VBAPete i select all text files (nearly 30 files). i am able to import the files and format the data with delimiter using the code given in the link. the only problem the all the sheets are imported to new workbook. But i need to import them to existing workbook as i mentioned in my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after OP's new request (see bottom of the answer)

change

```
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(wkbAll.Sheets.Count)
```

to

```
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wkbAll.Sheets(wkbAll.Sheets.Count)
```

thus you can also change the whole section:

```
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
Set wkbAll = ThisWorkbook
wkbAll.Activate
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(wkbAll.Sheets.Count)
wkbTemp.Close (False)
```

to

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    .Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
    .Close False
End With
```

and get rid of `wkbTemp` variable at all

---

should you need to copy data into an existing worksheet of the same workbook, then substitute

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    .Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
    .Close False
End With
```

with

```
With Worksheets("Data1") '<--| change "Data1" to your actual name of existing sheet where to paste data into
    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy .Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: @Ivars, did you get through it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, After rewriting code to do **delimiter format**  in the temperory file and then copy the data to my excel workbook along with the changes you have specified.The code is working as i would like it to be. Awesome. I reposted the full code with the changes.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the data into the same sheet instead of creating new one. For example if tthe file name is **Data1** , If i have a sheet name called **Data1** in the workbook, is it possible to clear the contents of the sheet and update the sheet with new data

Comment: Yeah but i have multiple data sheets like Data1,Data2,Data3. Data1 text file should copy into Data1 sheet and Data2 file  into Data2 sheet and so on. Tahnk you once again

Comment: then just use `With Worksheets(textFileName)`, where `textFileName` is a variable storing the current text file name

Comment: Sorry can you show me how to do that, i am rteally new to VBA but in the process of learning. But what about the delimiter format.Is it possible for you to  edit my code and update it?

Comment: The above code for copying into same sheet omits the delimiter format.

Comment: Is there a solution for my second problem? Thanks once again

Comment: please make a _new_ post for _new_ question. be sure to add all relevant info and examples along with your code attempts specifying what's wrong with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133568/discussion-between-lvars-and-user3598756).