# Import multiple txt files wrong date and number format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import multiple txt files into excel. This code is working perfectly but it messes up **date and number formats**. For instance, it is **omitting zeros for numbers higher than 1000**. I tried the solution described in this other post: [Excel VBA - Importing multiple txt files but not able to convert data to text format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750555/excel-vba-importing-multiple-txt-files-but-not-able-to-convert-data-to-text-fo?rq=1)  with FieldInfo for the columns that are showing this kind of format problems, (which are columns 18,62,63,64,65) but it is still not working. Here the original code I'm using.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim sDelimiter As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sDelimiter = "|"

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If


Set wkbAll = Application.ActiveWorkbook
x = 1
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(18, 2), Array(62, 2), Array(63, 2), Array(64, 2), Array(65, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    .Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    .Close False
End With

x = x + 1

While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(18, 2), Array(62, 2), Array(63, 2), Array(64, 2), Array(65, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        .Sheets(1).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    End With
    x = x + 1
Wend

wkbAll.Save
ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wkbAll = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
I also found a code which actually solves the data format error, but it is just for importing 1 file. **I would need sth similar but for importing 39 txt files,** all of them with the same structure: around 70 columns , most of them string except for 3 which are number and 1 date (these last ones are causing trouble). Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub importCSV()

Dim ans As Integer:
ans = MsgBox("Click OK then select the file to import " & vbNewLine & "Data will be imported at position of active cell", vbOKCancel)
If ans = vbCancel Then
    GoTo exitpoint
End If
'data will be imported at position of active cell as first data element
Dim ColumnsType() As Variant
strFilepath = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'prompt user for filepath of import file
If strFilepath = False Then Exit Sub
Dim intFileNo As Integer
Dim nCol As Long
Dim strLine As String
Dim varColumnFormat As Variant
Dim varTemp As Variant

' Read first line of file to figure out how many columns there are
intFileNo = FreeFile()
Open strFilepath For Input As #intFileNo
Line Input #intFileNo, strLine
Close #intFileNo
varTemp = Split(strLine, ",")
nCol = UBound(varTemp)
ReDim varColumnFormat(0 To nCol)

' get the columns to import as Text from user
Dim textit() As String
textit = Split(InputBox("Enter columns to format as Text (e.g 1,3,5)" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Or OK/Cancel to use file definition"), ",")
ub = UBound(textit)
If ub = -1 Then 'if nothing entered, promp for file for column formats
    Dim strFilename2 As String: strFilename2 = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If strFilename2 = "" Or strFilename2 = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No column Types have been entered." & Chr(10) & "Exiting Sub.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim strFileContent As String
    Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
    Open strFilename2 For Input As #iFile
        strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
    Close #iFile
    textit = Split(strFileContent, ",")
    ub = UBound(textit)
    If ub < nCol Then 'confirm there are enough column denoted in the file
        MsgBox "There are too few columns denoted in your column format file." & Chr(10) & "Exiting Sub.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i = 0 To nCol 'assing the file values to the column format array
        varColumnFormat(i) = Int(textit(i))
    Next
Else 'assign the entered columns a Text format value in the column format array
    Dim uBi As Integer
    uBi = 0
    For i = 0 To nCol
        If i + 1 = textit(uBi) Then
            varColumnFormat(i) = xlTextFormat
            uBi = WorksheetFunction.Min(uBi + 1, ub)
        Else
            varColumnFormat(i) = xlGeneralFormat
       End If
    Next
End If
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFilepath, Destination:=ActiveCell)     'creates the query to import the CSV. All following lines are properties of this
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileOtherDelimiter = Application.International(xlListSeparator) 'uses system setting => EU countries = ';' and US = ','
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = varColumnFormat  'set column data types as input by user
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False         'this is neccesary so a second import can be done
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete  'deletes the query
MsgBox "Date Import Done!"
exitpoint:
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Have you tried recording a macro to do this process and see what differences occur? Is the date/time correct when you record a macro?

Comment: Also, we will require an example of the file you are trying to pull in. Seems like you just haven't set number columns to be Text - this is what happens with long numbers (Card Details for example)

Comment: Hi. I have 39 txt files to import. They all have the same structure and 70 columns. Most of the columns are string but some of them are numbers and one is date. These last ones are the ones causing problems (colums 18, 62, 63, 64 and 65). 
How can I set these columns to be Text?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your data type when pull from the text files. You need to change your `18, 2` to `18, 1`

```
Number Format
1      Text
2      General
3      I think this means skip?
4      Date
```

So you need to change your `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(18, 2), Array(62, 2), Array(63, 2), Array(64, 2), Array(65, 2))` to the data type you want. Text is best for numbers over I think **7** digits. Use date for your date column, but you will need to check if it's the right format

So If all the below are numbers and the last is date, it would look like this

```
While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(18, 1), Array(62, 1), Array(63, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(65, 4)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        .Sheets(1).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: The second argument of each element in the `FieldInfo` is an [xlColumnDataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype) - `9` is "skip column", `3`-`8` and `10` are all different Date formats.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: I already tried that and it's not chaning my data formats... I found another code which actually solves the error of data formats but the problem now is that it is just importing 1 txt file.  Does anyone know how to extend this code to import multiple txt files? I will add it to my original question so you can see all the code. Thank you for your feedback so far!

Comment: This would be quite unlikely, make sure you have changed both sections of those data formats, as you have two - one for `x = 1` and one for `x = 1 + 1`

Comment: Yes I changed it in both sections but data formats are still wrong... Meanwhile I added the code which is fixing data format issue in the update...hope this can be extended to multiple files??