# Pulling multiple txt files into existing excel workbook, organizing text file into worksheets based on text file name

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I've found to pull text files into excel and import each text file into an existing worksheet based on the text file name.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755181 by [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait)

```
    Sub ImportTXTFiles()
        Dim fso As Object
        Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
        Dim qt As QueryTable
        Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                     (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

        For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
            ' FINDS EXISTING WORKSHEET
            For Each xlsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If xlsheet.Name = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "") Then
                    xlsheet.Activate
                    GoTo ImportData
                End If
            Next xlsheet

      
            ' IMPORT DATA FROM TEXT FILE
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
              Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1))
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"

                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

            For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
                qt.Delete
            Next qt
        Next txtfile

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

        Set fso = Nothing
    End Sub
```

My only issue is, this code replaces the data that is already in the worksheet. I want to be able to continue to pull data in and have it "imported" into the next available row in the appropriate sheet based on the text file name.

Comment: Try `Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1))`

Comment: FYI FSO has `GetBaseName` which will return the filename without any extension, given a file name or full path.  Eg `fso.getbasename("C:\Temp\blah.txt")` returns `blah` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getbasename-method

Answer (score 1):

- Locate the last data row with `End`.
- Add special handling code for blank sheet.
- `GoTo ImportData` is in your code, but there isn't line number `ImportData`.
- I would suggest to avoid using `GoTo`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTXTFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
    
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, sShtName As String
    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
        ' FINDS EXISTING WORKSHEET
        Set oSht = Nothing
        sShtName = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "")
        For Each xlsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If xlsheet.Name = sShtName Then
                Set oSht = xlsheet
            End If
        Next xlsheet
        If oSht Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Can't find sheet " & sShtName
        Else
            ' IMPORT DATA FROM TEXT FILE
            Dim c As Range
            With oSht
                Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If c.Row > 1 Then
                    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
                ElseIf Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
                    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            End If
            With oSht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, Destination:=c)
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
                
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
            
            For Each qt In oSht.QueryTables
                qt.Delete
            Next qt
        End If
    Next txtfile
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"
    
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)