# Importing a text file using Application.GetOpenFilename

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import the full contents of a text file onto a specific sheet within a specific workbook. I can get it to work using the following code when importing another Excel file, but am having trouble figuring out how to do the same concept with a text file. I'm pretty new to VBA code so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sample code I use daily for an excel import:

```
Sub Run_NEW_ROB()

    'IDeaS ROB Extract Import

    Cur_file = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    OldFN = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select IDeaS ROB Extract")
    If LCase(OldFN) = "false" Then
    MsgBox "You Did Not Select A File - Stopping"

    Exit Sub
    Else

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=OldFN
    Set WBK = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    Sheets("Hotel").Select
    Range("A1:Y366").Copy
    Windows(Cur_file).Activate
    Sheets("H_CUR").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    WBK.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows(Cur_file).Activate

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=OldFN
    Set WBK = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets("Market Segments").Select
    Range("A1:K10221").Copy
    Windows(Cur_file).Activate
    Sheets("SEG_CUR").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    WBK.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows(Cur_file).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: This should help: [Importing text file into excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet).

Comment: You can use `Workbooks.OpenText` method. To see the syntax, record a macro while importing your text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses *GetOpenFilename* to pick and open the destination workbook.  It also uses *GetOpenFilename* to pick the text file.

The text is imported into a specific cell in a specific worksheet.  The destination workbook is then saved and closed:

```
Sub OpenDemo()
    Dim b1 As Workbook, s As String, J As Long

'
'   Select and open the destination workbook
'
    s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open s
    Set b1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("xxx").Select
'
'   Select and open the text file
'   put the data in B9 and down
'
    s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Close #1
    Open s For Input As #1
    J = 9
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TextLine
        Cells(J, "B") = TextLine
        J = J + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
'
'   Save and close the destination workbook
'
    b1.Save
    b1.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple version from @Gary's Student.
This version does not promp to select the destination file, but does propmt to select a txt file from win explorer to import. It will import the txt file contents into the active worksheet in the active workbook,

```
Sub txtimport()
Dim b1 As Workbook, s As String, J As Long

s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Close #1
Open s For Input As #1
J = 3
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, TextLine
    Cells(J, "A") = TextLine
    J = J + 1
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a link, so that readers can more easily find the passage you quoted in its original context?