# How to open a txt file with vba code and and copy its contents to excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open multiple txt files from same folder and copy its contents to a single excel file (like a template) to modify the values and then, I need to copy the modified values from excel to txt files. How can we do this VBA automation? any reply would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide more information ? What do the data in the txt files look like ? Do you need to put the content of you txt file into a specific cell ? Which cells do you need to put back into a txt file ?

Comment: @Teasel Thanks for your concern.I need to copy the contents of txt file from its 4th line to excel file's 1st sheet (staring cell: A4), I have some formulas to modify the data of 1st sheet in 2nd sheet. Then the modified data from 2nd sheet need to get copy & paste into the same txt file's 4th line and then save it. Kindly look into it if you find time.

Comment: I wrote an answer that should work. If that's the case accept the answer it'd be kind :)

Comment: @Teasel Thanks for your valuable reply. It works great with one file.        For multiple files on same folder for the repetitive action what should I add there? You have any idea?                                                                                 and one more, i need to copy the contents of txt file from 4th line and paste it on excel file at staring cell A4?

Comment: The answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749626/5836929 will give you a good lead (it's what you need, you call you method in the loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a file by using the following method ([found there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267603/5836929), adapt it!)

```
Sub OpenAndImportTxtFile()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Sheet where you want to import

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Open("path and name of your file")

    wbO.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsI.Cells

    wbO.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

And export your sheet with the following method ([found there](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/664194-vba-save-specific-sheet-work-book-txt-file.html))

```
Sub SaveFile()
Dim ans As Long
Dim sSaveAsFilePath As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

sSaveAsFilePath = "path and name of your file"

If Dir(sSaveAsFilePath) <> "" Then
    ans = MsgBox("File " & sSaveAsFilePath & " exists.  Overwrite?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
    If ans <> vbYes Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Kill sSaveAsFilePath
    End If
End If

Sheet1.Copy '//Copy sheet to new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sSaveAsFilePath, xlTextWindows '//Save as text (tab delimited) file

If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then '//Double sure we don't close this workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End If

My_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume My_Exit
End Sub
```

Call them with

```
OpenAndImportTxtFile
SaveFile
```

Answer (score 1):

There are pretty good guides I used to do the same work like you.

For Text to Excel:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

[vba: Importing text file into excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet)

For Excel to Text:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to merge all text files into one single file.  How about this option?

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim vNewFile As Variant
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim sLine As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(sPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
                sPath = sPath & Application.PathSeparator
            End If
        Else
             'Path cancelled, exit
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    vNewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("CombinedFile.txt", "Text files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Please enter the combined filename.")
    If TypeName(vNewFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.txt")
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        lFile = FreeFile
        Open CStr(sFile) For Input As #lFile
        Do Until EOF(lFile)
            Line Input #1, sLine
            sTxt = sTxt & vbNewLine & sLine
        Loop
        Close lFile
        sFile = Dir()
    Loop
    lFile = FreeFile
    Open CStr(vNewFile) For Output As #lFile
    Print #lFile, sTxt
    Close lFile
End Sub
```