# Can I import txt files into excel using this method?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to load in multiple txt files into my excel sheet using a sub function as shown below. However, the data is tab delimited - how do I get the data to be imported with this? "   " doesn't seem to work.

Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub InsrtInfo()

Dim strFileToOpen As String

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose A", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt,")
    copyDataFromTXTFileToSheet strFileToOpen, " ", "A"
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose B", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt,")
    copyDataFromTXTFileToSheet strFileToOpen, " ", "B"
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="C", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt,")
    copyDataFromTXTFileToSheet strFileToOpen, " ", "C"
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="D", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt,")
    copyDataFromTXTFileToSheet strFileToOpen, " ", "D"
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="E", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt,")
    copyDataFromTXTFileToSheet strFileToOpen, " ", "E"


End Sub
```

Comment: Parameter required instead of "  " was vbTab!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a great answer written by Siddharth Rout** in the thread I linked below.

I used the **Query Tables** method to import over 3000 tab-delimited text files into 7 separate workbooks and it worked great, **however you will find other ways to import text files in that thread too.**

[VBA Importing text file into Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks this is a great thread! I'd like to see if the method above can be added to the list of ways :)