# vba listing content from txt file into excel

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to get my vba script to copy content from a text file and place it in individual cells. So far im able to pull content from a file, but it places it all one cell only. Is there a way to modify the script below to have it in each cell after every "enter" on the txt file?

```
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objStartFolder = "C:\Users\mohammad.anwar\Desktop\Newfolder4\"
    Dim strNow, strDD, strMM, strYYYY, strFulldate
    strYYYY = DatePart("yyyy", Now())
    strMM = Right("0" & DatePart("m", Now()), 2)
    strDD = Right("0" & DatePart("d", Now()), 2)
    fulldate = strYYYY & strMM & strDD
    ForReading = 1
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files


    For Each objFile In colFiles
    strFileName = objFile.Name


    If InStr(strFileName, fulldate) > 0 = True Then


    Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder + strFileName, 1)
    Content = file.ReadAll
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Content
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by implementing another section from a previous post found.
for reference purpose.
[vba: Importing text file into excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/vba-importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet)

script was added in the **IF** string and was able to find the file by date and list the content in the file on each cell

`Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\"Your file path"\ & **strFileName,** Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub`