# Not placing the zeros

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, paste

I have a `TXT file`, but when I insert it in my Excel it is removing the `zeros` and I don't know why it is happening and I tried to put the field type `TEXT` (but it changes it back to general) and also in my macro to put `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`.

```
  Sub Get_Data_FromFile()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browser for your file & Import range", FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *txt*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:U1000").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asiento único").Range("E18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use a method that allows you to set the column type as it is imported see first part of top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267459/importing-text-file-into-excel-sheet

Comment: The problem is that when I make the copy it is copying it to me with the general format (I discovered it with the debug). But I can't find information on how to prevent EXCEL from doing that.

Comment: did you look at the answers in the link.  Instead of opening directly you need to use a different method.  In the first method in the top answer it shows how to import it and dictate the type with the `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array()` part.

Comment: I didn't see the method (it's the first time I use macros), but I don't understand where in my code I implement it. Looking at the documentation they use xlTextFormat and it works it leaves me the cells in text type, but it still keeps copying if as if it were a general cell.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asiento único").Cells.NumberFormat = "@"` Before Paste? When you Open the TXT File via Excel, does it have the Zeros before copying?

Comment: When I perform a debug and place a `breakponit ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Single Seat").Range("E18").PasteSpecial xlTextFormat` it opens an excel and it does not have the zeros.

Comment: Do all 21 columns need to be imported as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Import Text File

- [Workbook.OpenText method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) (Microsoft Docs)
- Pay special attention to the `Origin` and [`FielInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype) parameters.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 1
    
    Const dName As String = "Asiento único"
    Const dFirstCell As String = "E18"
    Const Cols As String = "A:U"
    
    Dim msgString As String
    Dim IsSuccess As Variant
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCell)
    
    ' Create the FieldInfo parameter (all columns as text)
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dws.Columns(Cols)
    Dim dfCol As Long: dfCol = dcrg.Columns(1).Column
    Dim dlCol As Long: dlCol = dcrg.Columns(dcrg.Columns.Count).Column
    Dim cArr As Variant: ReDim cArr(0 To dlCol - dfCol)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = dfCol To dlCol
        cArr(c - dfCol) = Array(c, xlTextFormat)
    Next c
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Browser for your file & Import range", _
        FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *txt*")

    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        
        Workbooks.OpenText _
            Filename:="C:\Test\2021\70386358\Test.txt", _
            Origin:=xlWindows, _
            StartRow:=sfRow, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=True, _
            FieldInfo:=cArr
        
        Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(sws.UsedRange, sws.Columns(Cols))
        
        msgString = "Copied from" & vbLf & srg.Address(0, 0, , True) & vbLf
        
        srg.Copy
        dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        dws.Activate
        msgString = msgString & "to" & vbLf _
            & ActiveWindow.Selection.Address(0, 0, , True)
        dfCell.Select

        IsSuccess = True
         
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If IsSuccess Then
        MsgBox msgString, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```